# Estimation of measurements with a multimeter

Tags: power-supply, multimeter, debugging

I have an EMU-APS PCI sound card which was damaged by a bad PC power supply.
The card is old but costly to replace and of very high capability, so I am attempting to repair it.
As it is a proprietary device I do not have a circuit diagram, but I intend to replace the major ICs and the power supply regulators.

I have ordered replacement ICs but would like to try to determine if the existing ones are in fact faulty

My audio card (PCI) recognized by windows, does not, however, give sound.
Even if an audio file is playing and the graphical peak levels of the mixer are moving up and down, there is no sound. Problems with drivers and anything else related to software have been ruled out. Previously there was a problem with the PSU, which proved to be faulty.
I have detached from the card four voltage regulators, and three integrated circuits: two identical amplifiers and a digital signal intensity controller. I have taken measurements with the multi-meter and would like your opinion on which of these components should be replaced, based on these results. The first measurement concerns three of the four voltage regulators (the fourth was destroyed during detachment) and gives the output current in relation to the input current.

---

UPDATE (1)

Based on comment from several people I now realise that my measurement method ws incorrect.
The following measurements were made with  multimeter on a DC Volts range.
I have left the old material as prior answers and comments refer to it and they would be meaningless if the old material was deleted.

> See datasheet here for 79M08 regulator. See diagram top right page 1. 0.33 uF cap or larger is recommended for all 3 regulators. Output cap optional.. –

I made new measurements for the positive regulators, using a 0.33 μF cap, as described in the datasheet for 79M08 regulator and the results are these :

[image: New measurements for positive Regulators]

I am seeing that :

1. For the +8V Regulator, when Input Voltage goes over 8V, Output Voltage stays constant at about 8V.
2. For the +5V Regulator, when Input Voltage goes over 5V, Output Voltage stays constant at about 5V.

Isn't this an indication that these two Regulators are functional ?

I, also have read another comment :

> ...When testing negative regulator the Vin MUST be negative relative to ground. –

But I do not know how to apply negative Volt Input, relative to ground, so I did not test the negative Reg

---

Older material:

The second measurement concerns the three integrated circuits and gives the voltage drop. The measurements were done by placing the negative probe of the multi-meter in the ground of the IC's and the positive wire in all other pins consecutively. The multi-meter was put in diode mode.
Here are the results :

[image: 1]...................Voltage Regulators results..................

[image: 2]...................Amplifier A results.........................

[image: 3]...................Amplifier B results.........................

[image: 4]...................Volume Control results......................

ulator.

Comment: Can you show a schematic or explain how the negative rail is built?

Comment: Why would you measure the voltage using diode mode on your multimeter? This measurement is most likely useless and might have damaged your amplifiers.

Comment: I am sorry, i know only the basics. I do not understand what is a negative rail. Can you explain it, so for me to understand ? Is it the path of wires that ends to the ground ?

Comment: Can you tell us the IC part numbers?  It appears that the +8 and -8 and +5V voltage regulators are not producing the correct voltages - could be faulty regulators (but all 3??) or something else drawing excessive current pulling the voltage rails down.  Were those voltage regulator measurement done with the regulators in-circuit, or after you took them out of the circuit?  Make and model of the audio card would also help.

Comment: @kraka - Hi, (a) I see this Q follows your [previous one](/q/678430) where you are using the DMM continuity test to diagnose your PCI audio card. (b) Questions about consumer electronics are [off-topic](/help/on-topic) here. (c) You asked for "*{our} opinion on which of these components should be replaced*". Repair questions are only on-topic if you: "demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired". We generally mean that you should supply schematics and other "design-level" details. Without that info, this question isn't suitable for the site.

Comment: @SamGibson I have to disagree that this is off topic since the question is not about how to use it. I also disagree that it is an opinion based question (it is not a debate to which component is at fault but which are more likely to be at fault) based on experiences. That being said, I agree that the OP doesn't seem to have a good understanding of the design or electronic in general. I would say that the question is very unclear and doesn't have much chance of getting better.

Comment: @kraka, I would really like to help you, but, you have to do some homework first. Before debugging a PCI card, maybe you should start with a simpler project. Try something on a breadboard. Anything that will have some analog design in it to learn the basic. You can find many books on the subject. That way you'll have a better understanding of debugging approach and how electronics work in general. Sorry I can't help you more.

Comment: @Julien - "*I have to disagree that this is off topic since the question is not about how to use it*" I didn't say it was a usage question; I said it was a consumer electronics question. You can't disagree it is that :) Those are off-topic as there is simply too much we won't know about a specific product, if schematics aren't given. Unless the device is trivial (e.g. a crockpot) most attempted consumer device questions are unsuccessful due to lack of info, yet they waste time until people give up. This site has a smaller on-topic list than a typical forum. Ask on [Meta] if you want to discuss

Comment: the amplifier and volume control results show no power supply voltages

Comment: @Peter Bennett
All these measurements done, after i took the components out of the circuit.
As i already told (in my question), issue may connected to the faulty PSU of my PC, that i have already replaced with a good one. PC would often shut down, randomly, before i replace the faulty PSU.

Comment: @jsotola
Thanks for your reply. It's what I expected. I asked a simple question and I expected a simple answer. I think this is a democratic site (okay, there are rules because democracy doesn't mean abuse and impunity. And I know this well because i was born in the country that gave birth to democracy). I did not force anyone to answer my question.

Comment: @kraka  I'm  a group admin. I'm sorry that you have had a confusing set of responses. A problem is that your problem is not as simple as it appears to you. You are using a measurement approach which seems ar face value to be legitimate but, as Julien's answer explains, the method which you are using will produce spurious and semi-random results. It's not meant to be used the way that you are using it. Please read Julien's answer. I will add a short answer that explains what is needed to measure the regulators correctly.

Comment: For interest, where are you located? And what is the brand and model of your SPI audio card. Someone may be willing to give you one depending on how highly specified it is and where you are located. (eg I have a number of not overly fancy ones that are unneeded.)

Comment: @kraka  Read Julien's anwer. Your meter MUST NOT be in diode test mode . In diode test mode all the readings are totally wrong and totally useless. You MUST set it to an appropriate volt mode. Probably 10V. When testing negative regulator the Vin MUST be negative relative to ground.

Comment: @kraka  Your new measurements show that the +8V and +5V regulator are working correctly. || To apply a negative input you can use a "normal" power supply with the input leads swapped. ie  Power supply +ve connects to  regulator ground  input. Power supply -ve input connected to regulator -ve input. || When testing with input leads swapped the device under test must NOT be connected to the power supply in any other way. For isolated components this is not an issue. If testing "in circuit" the device under test would need to be fully disconnected. (In circuit testing also has other issues).

Comment: If you please, I would like to ask you for clarification on wiring.
As shown in the diagramm of datasheet for 79M08 regulator, the Positive end of 0.33 μF cap is attached to the Power Supply's +Ve input (which is attached to the  Regulator's +Ve input). And the Negative end of the cap is attached to the Ground of the Requlator.
If i test with input leads swapped, then what will be the connection of the cap ?
a) The Positive end of the cap...

Comment: a) The Positive end of the cap attached to the Power Supply's +Ve input (which is attached to the  Regulator's -Ve input) and the Negative end of the cap is attached to the Ground of the Requlator ? 
or
b) The Positive end of the cap attached to the Power Supply's -Ve input (which is attached to the  Regulator's +Ve input) and the Negative end of the cap is attached to the Ground of the Requlator ? 

Also i am confused about the Power Supply's +Ve. Why Should be connected to the Regulator's -Ve input and not to the Regulator's Ground ?

Comment: @kraka  My apologies. My word desription above was incorrect. I have corrected it. But: PSU + to Regulator gnd. PSU - to regulator -Vin. || If the 0.33uF is not polarised (as would usually be the case) then polarity of connection does not matter. If polarisd then Cap+ needs to be maintained as most positive.

Answer (score 1):

As Julien's answer explains, a diode test measurement will not produce the answers that you are looking for.

If you wish to determine if regulators are functioning then you either need to

- test them in circuit with the device powered up, and measure input and output voltages

or

- Test them out of circuit BUT with power applied, and suitable minimum external components connected, and measure voltages.

Out of circuit testing requires.

- Application of an in-specification input voltage between IC Vin and ground.
- Connection of suitable capacitors from Vin to ground and vout to ground.
- Then, measurement of Vout.
- With some regulators you may need a load resistor.
- With some regulators you may need extra resistors between Vout and Vref (~= gnd pin) and Vref and ground. This depends on the regulator type.

You should provide regulator part numbers.

It is likely that the path you have taken will not lead to a successful repair. A PCI audio card is a complex device, with most of the complexity being within the ICs used. If these are damaged it can only be repaired by IC replacement and this is unlikely to be economic (in the event that the ICs are available), and to require repair skills substantially greater than you probably have. That's not meant to be in any way rude - just probably factual.

If you provide regulator part numbers we MAY be able to help, but it is unlikely to lead to a good result, sadly.

Comment: As i described in my question, all the measurements were made when the components were de-soldered. I used an external device to apply voltage to the "input" pin of regulator and as seen from the first table i had upload, this voltage was increasing for each meassurement (1.75, 3.5, 5, 6.5, 8, 9.5, 12,5). So i am in your below (lastly) section of "or". What i did not do from the five  requirements that you described was the connection of suitable capacitors from Vin to ground and Vout to ground.

Comment: As for provide regulator part numbers, somebody before told that my question is out of topic because it refers to commercial parts. Even if part numbers do not have behind of them any company and they are general types, how to know if a general type is a patent of one Company. 
For example if we were talking for cars and i refer to "Jeep", would not have come SamGibson and told that i am "of topic" because i refer to Chrysler ?  Anyway i trust you, and provide the part number of regulators.79MO8A,78MO8A,78MO5A. The two amplifiers is 134UA, and the volume controller is the 3310-KS. 
My Au...

Comment: My Audio Card brand is EMU-APS.
About the ICs that are the most complex parts of an audio card and must be replaced, i already have order the two amplifiers and the Volume Controller. 
I must say something about the skills that i must have to do the replacement. I do not misunderstood you. I know that you want to help and i appreciate this. Obvious you are referring to the 98% of the area down of the curve, and this is scientifically - right when 
you talk with unknown people.

Comment: @Kraka I'll suggest a possibly better place to ask this question in my next comment. Note that people with a small diamond after their name (as in my case) are system administrators. You have been talking to another one here. What they say is usually how things are meant to be. Trying to work with them is very usually a good idea. || You say that you are competent, but also you say that you only understand the basics. IF you are using your meter in the diode test mode, as you appear to be saying, then as explained by Julien and others, it is completely inappropriate and all results are invalid

Comment: @Kraka For an excellent  forum that supports discussion look at http://www.piclist.com (don't be put off by the presentation or the PIC in the name). Then visit http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist, join the mailing list & say hello. Provide as much detail of your requirements as possible. If you wish I can post your photos on a website.  Like here, there are people there who know almost everything (collectively). The site supports a conversational approach. Some SE members are also members (myself included). It's a very useful complement to this site for questions of this sort.

Comment: See datasheet [here](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc79m00-d.pdf) for 79M08 regulator. See diagram top right page 1. 0.33 uF cap or larger is recommended for all 3 regulators. Output cap optional..

Comment: About piclist.com :
The site you recommend is a new hope for me and I want to thank you for it.

Comment: About  datasheet for 79M08 regulator :
This is the most useful information I have received so far.

Comment: About diamonds :
I never look at diamonds next to someone's name or on his finger but at the answer itself and only that, and since the person who owns the diamond took the trouble to give an explanation to my question, if and only if I judge that his answer (like yours) is well - intentioned then I proceed to dialogue.

Comment: At last please let me say something about skills :
Indeed, I have said that I only know the basics. I was only referring to theory. It is entirely possible for someone who has mastered the theory but cannot do it on his own, to come and ask me to do a difficult soldering on a IC. It is not surprising, even though I know only the basics of the theory, to do it successfully.
Don't you know about excellent guitarists who are self-taught, and know nothing about Music Theory, as well as excellent musicologists who can't play an instrument very well? But even ...

Comment: But even when it comes to theory, just because I know the basics doesn't mean that my learning rate is slow. It can also be very fast.
Two days ago I didn't know what a "negative railway" was, when a friend here asked me to provide it. But today, after this friend's refusal to explain to me (and rightly so), I know what it is, after studying the appropriate book. For both of the above cases, here in my country we say:
"ἕτερον ἑκάτερον"

Comment: @Kraka Failing to note what a moderator says when he gives advice on how the site works is highly likely to cause you major problems. ALL of life has rules - some of them less obvious than others. This site is no exception. We cannot change the rules, but we can try to understand how to work within them to our best advantage. If you explain  your overall situation better (repairing an expensive card, no circuit diagram available, possibly blown up by a bad power supply which is now fixed, replacing the major ICs as well as the regulators, ...) you would be likely to do better.

Comment: @kraka  ... Also: Please take this as good advice. Complaining it shouldn't be so won't help you --> Re competence: You may be learning fast (hopefully so) BUT your described actions to date suggest you are an enthusiastic beginner who is doing some incompetent things. That is acceptable IF the beginner will listen and learn. So far I have seen no indication that you understood that using the diode test range was completely inappropriate and that your results are meaningless. Instead insisting you are competent but not dealing with this major point does not encourage people to help you.

Comment: As i wrote in my comment, i have already order the components i have refer to. And i did this not because i made a false diagnose with "help" of diode mode but because nobody, before post my Question here, show me a way to make a diagnosis on these components. 
After my question, i have received a way to do it in last comment before 2 Answers.

I take  seriously, administrator's advice and next time i will explain my overall situation better.

Comment: I did understand that using the diode test range was completely inappropriate and results were meaningless.
I re-read all my comments and i cannot find there, an indication shows that i did not understand it.
Only before the two Answers, i found something : It is when i 
say "thanks for your reply, it's what i expect it..." @jsotola.
But this was before the two answers.
Why you have seen no indication that i understood the 
inappropriate test of diode mode ?

Answer (score 0):

This answer addresses an important aspect of your problem.

- It does NOT tell you whether there is anything wrong with your regulators.
- It does explain that your measurement is unsuitable for trying to determine what you need to know.

This is an important first step in finding out what you need to know.

---

Here is a crash course in multimeter measurement.

A DMM or Digital Multi Meter can only measure voltage.
All the other measurement are declination of it.
For instance, current measurement is actually a measurement of the voltage across a small resistor. Since the value of the resistor is known, it is possible to convert the voltage of that resistor (shunt) into current.

The resistance measurement is usually done by a constant current source (known to the multimeter) that is fed to your probes. The multimeter then measure the voltage. Since it knows both the voltage and current, it can figure the resistance.

Continuity is a declination of the ohm measurement.
The main difference is that the current it can output is often set at 10mA. Whenever the voltage drops below a certain threshold, the multimeter will beep.

The diode measurement is exactly like the continuity but instead of displaying the value in ohm, it displays it in V.

So, when I say, you can't measure in circuit with resistance, diode or continuity mode, it is because they are acting as a power source and are powering your board. The measurement they give is simply meaningless. It is critical to understand this before using a DMM, otherwise, you get confusing results.

Now, the first measurement, you are using in Volt mode the DMM and they make sense. The second part, you are using it in diode mode, which makes no sense because the circuit is not powered. You are virtually testing the conductivity between random paths of an unpowered device. The value you are measuring are in fact the ESD protection circuits! To make those measurement, you need to do them in circuit, meaning fully powered.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If it does not answer the question, it should be in a comment. If it is a discussion it should be in chat.

Comment: @Julien I have undeleted your answer because I consider it is useful in the context given. The OP has a major problem in that they are using a multimeter incorrectly and drawing false conclusions - you know that. Your answer addresses their confusion -   a necessary part of realising where they are going wrong. If desired you COULD modify your answer to make it clear how you answer helps. I have edited it. You are welcome to - any of:  - delete again if you wish / improve on my edit / remove my edit / other. Thanks for assisting a new user.